# How to get x,y coordinates of android native app using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

How to get x,y coordinates of android native app using selenium java web driver.

I am using appium. My app opens the android image gallery. As the uiautomatorviewer doesn't show the layout for it. I couldn't able to click an image.

Looks like moveToElement, mouseMoveAt etc is working only for browsers. What are the options available for native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using the below code. By tapping in a certain position I could able to pick an image.

```
        HashMap<String, Integer> tapObject = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        tapObject.put("x", 100); // in pixels from left

        tapObject.put("y", 300); // in pixels from top

        driver.executeScript("mobile: tap", tapObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to Appium. Appium ads an extra layer on top of Selenium which can help you to automate native iOS and Android applications.

http://appium.io

Comment: I edited my question. Could you be more specific. What kind of classes I need to use