# How can I able to press search button from keyboard of android device?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, appium

I am using appium for mobile app testing and language as java.

I have given below coding to enter the text by using sendkeys.

After entering the text, I need to press the search button from keyboard.

For that I have used key code event to press the search button. But the search action doesn't happen for me.

```
@Test
public static void test_demo() throws Exception {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mytextfield"));
    element.sendKeys("Chennai");

    // press search button
    driver.sendKeyEvent(84);

}
```

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue, did you found any helpful solution?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to developer ? You should check with them if keycode 84 is equivalent to pressing on search button on your app. It depends on how it is coded. I have faced similar issue previously where enter keycode was not behaving as it presses the enter button on the android keyboard so my keycode press script wasn't doing anything. Then I used coordinates in that case to press on the Enter button from the keyboard.

Comment: I have tried to enter the text via keycode(for example: Mumbai). I can able to enter the text in the text box using keyboard. But, search button press is not working for me. Then, how to use coordinates to click the search button from the keyboard.

Comment: You can use driver.tap method. To get the x and y coordinates-  you have to calculate the the pixels to reach Search button. You can project the screen of the device using UIAutomator of android sdk and check the pixels. May be some trials can give you good exact coordinates. And offcourse this strategy is very poor for having a reusable script which can run on multiple devices. Also check this link -(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538923/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-of-android-native-app-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine;

```
element.click();    
element.sendKeys("text");    
driver.executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "search"));
```